# How to bind activity result to ExpressionTextBox?

Tags: workflow-foundation

i have a designer activity and i would like to bind the bellow ExpressionTextBox to the 
activity result.

The xaml:

```
ExpressionTextBox Expression="{Binding Path=ModelItem.context, Mode=OneTime, 
Converter={StaticResource ArgumentToExpressionConverter}
```

The activity result in the code behind:

```
protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)

           string str = "hello world"
           Result.Set(context, str);
```

Thanks, 
Noah

Answer (score 0):

Here's an overview on using ExpressionTextBox:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cathyk/archive/2009/11/12/expressiontextbox-101.aspx